# Can Matrix Scaling be defined as a linear operator?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

In Matrix scaling we multiply each element of a matrix by a non-zero scalar value. I was just wondering, whether Matrix Scaling can be used as a linear operator over matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $\mathbb{R}^{n,m}$ denotes real matrices of $m$ rows and $n$ columns, you can define, for $c\in \mathbb{R}$, the map:

$$S_c:\mathbb{R}^{n,m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n,m}$$

$$M\mapsto cM$$

This is clearly a linear transformation: $S_c(\alpha A + \beta B) = c (\alpha A + \beta B)  =c \alpha A +c \beta B= \alpha S_c(A) + \beta S_c( B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix scaling *is* a linear operator over matrices.

Multiplying each element of the matrix, i.e. scalar multiplication, is a linear operator.

Scaling each row or column of the matrix corresponds to multiplying (to the left or to the right) by a diagonal matrix containing the scaling coefficients.